# is it possible to Pop up a window within another Pop up?

Tags: php, javascript, popup

I would like to know if its possible to pop up another pop up in a pop up? sorry if its confusing.

What I meant was (for example)

When you click a link in the main menu, a **pop up appearst** lets call it list of authors.

In that pop up, author names have their links, and when you click on it, another pop up should open (let us say to adding new title of published books under that author.

My question is, is that possible, if yes, how do i do that? If no, is there other ways to do this? I am asked to pop up the list in my program,under that list are links that will produce another pop up.

It was working properly before i turned my links into a pop up and now, it won't pop up the 2nd pop up.

here are codes that i have used (by request):

```
<a href="" onclick = javascript:Popup('comlist2.php') onmouseover="listmouseOver()" onmouseout="listmouseOut()";> <img src="images/comlist.jpg" id="clist" /></a>
//this is the code used in my index.php it calls the my comlist pop up with the help of
function Popup(url) 
        {
            popupWindow = window.open(url, 'main_pop','width=420,height=300,resizable=no,scrollbars=0,left = 430,top = 250');return false;
        }
```

in my comlist2.php,there is another:

```
function newPopup(url) 
        {
            popupWindow = window.open(url, 'main_pop','width=310,height=400,resizable=no,scrollbars=0,left = 430,top = 250');return false;
        }
<a href="" onclick = javascript:newPopup('addemp.php?com=<?php echo $file_cid ?>');><?php echo$file_cname?></a>
```

as you see,from the main, it pop ups' the list, in the list, there is also alink that must popup another php file

Comment: Please post some relevant code.  We cannot tell how you're attempting to do this.

Comment: I made a rollback of your last edit. If your problem get solved, please do not remove the code and put "CLOSED" in question's title. Questions are never closed here. Only terribly poor low quality posts are closed (by the community). If your problem is solved, just thank the one who answered your question, upvote the helpful answers and mark the most helpful answer accepted. Or when it's actually been unanswered, post the answer yourself.

Comment: @BalusC: thanks for the concern, anyway i cant upvote or accept answers here since im the one who solved it myself, i think thats ok right? i cant reanswer my post yet from what i read,it needs 8hrs before you could reanswer your post

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest instead of window popups using something like http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/
And have sub DIV's within that that appear and disappear.

Rule #1, People hate window popups. These instead are modal dialogs within the same window.

Comment: you mean a dialog box ? well my program is created using php,and a little javascript that produces my pop up, if it is a dialog box that you meant, i dont think i wont get what is expected to happen in my program

Comment: yes i did and i dont know how to mix it with my codes, i edited my post and posted my codes above

Comment: Perhaps spending a bit of time actually reading how to implement jQuery would greatly improve your website as a product. jQuery and it's jQueryUI package have the ability to make your website a lot nicer experience for your users as it allows you to have sliding effects, dynamic content and live reactions to your site via ajax.

Comment: i was told by my supervisor that instead of popup within a popup, i should output my should be 2nd pop to the same browser(popup) but thanks for your advice,il read it though :)